# Properly use Typescript Set<T> with intersecting types

Tags: typescript, generics, set, contravariance, intersection-types

I don't understand why the transpiler is complaining. Here are the basic type declarations:

```js
export enum SvgElementType {
  path = "path",
  circle = "circle",
}

export type SvgElement = {
  id: number;
  type: SvgElementType;
};

export type SvgPathElement = SvgElement & {
  type: SvgElementType.path;
  d: string;
};

export type SvgCircleElement = SvgElement & {
  type: SvgElementType.circle;
  cx: number;
  cy: number;
  radius: number;
};

export type Serializer<E extends SvgElement = SvgElement> = (element: E) => string;

const pathSerializer: Serializer<SvgPathElement> = e => "";
const circleSerializer: Serializer<SvgCircleElement> = e => "";

const serializers: Set<Serializer> = new Set();
serializers.add(pathSerializer); // <<<--- transpile error

// full TS error
// Argument of type 'Serializer<SvgPathElement>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Serializer<SvgElement>'.
//  Type 'SvgElement' is not assignable to type 'SvgPathElement'.
//    Property 'd' is missing in type 'SvgElement' but required in type '{ type: SvgElementType.path; d: string; }'.ts(2345)
```

the only way I found was to modify the declaration of the `Serializer` with `any` as default type:

```js
export type Serializer<E extends SvgElement = any> = (element: E) => string;
```

This flags me that there is probably a better way to preserve the minimum typing for the `serializers` Set iterator usage later on...

Comment: You will need runtime type checks anyway, so should you perhaps define all of your serialisers as `Serializer<SvgElement>` (i.e. remove the generic in `export type Serializer<E extends SvgElement = SvgElement>`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transpiler complains because you're effectively saying that you want a function that takes an `SvgElement` as input, but then you're trying to assign to it a function that takes an `SvgPathElement`.

This can't work - it would allow you to pass an `SvgElement` to your function that wants an `SvgPathElement`.

The formal term for this is "function parameters are *contravariant*".

Your code will require runtime type checks against the object being serialised anyway, so should you perhaps redefine your `Serializer` type without the generic? e.g.:

```js
export type Serializer = (element: SvgElement) => string;
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is complaining because your code, if allowed to compile, can cause type errors at runtime. For instance, if somebody were to do:

```
function serialize(e: SvgElement) {
  for (const s of serializers) {
    return s(element);
  }
}
```

that would compile, since every member of the set `serializers` is declared to accept any kind of `SvgElement` - but that is not actually true, because each `Serializer` only accepts a *particular* type of element, and would fail with type errors at runtime if called with a *different* type.

So how do you write a correct type?

Before I answer that, let's imagine how `serializers` will be used, because I am a bit surprised that `serializers` is a `Set`. How are we going to find the right `Serializer` in this `Set`? It seems to me that `Set` is a really poor data structure for this purpose, and a `Map`, or a dictionary object, would be a more straightforward choice.

Therefore, I'd use something like this:

```
export type SvgElementBase<T extends string> = {
  id: number;
  type: T;
}

export type SvgPathElement = SvgElementBase<"path"> & {
  d: string;
};

export type SvgCircleElement = SvgElementBase<"circle"> & {
  cx: number;
  cy: number;
  radius: number;
};

export type SvgElement = SvgPathElement | SvgCircleElement;
export type SvgElementType = SvgElement["type"];

export type Serializer<E extends SvgElement> = (e: E) => string;
export type Serializers = {[T in SvgElementType]: Serializer<SvgElement & SvgElementBase<T>>}

const serializers: Serializers = {
  path: (e) => `path ${e.d}`,
  circle: (e) => `circle at (${e.cx},${e.cy}) with radius ${e.radius}`,
}

function lookupSerializer<E extends SvgElement>(type: E["type"]): Serializer<E> { // the things we do for type safety
  return serializers[type];
}

export function serialize(element: SvgElement) {
  return lookupSerializer(element.type)(element);
}
```

By declaring `serializers` with a mapped type, we can express that the types of the key and the value are related, i.e. that the serializer registered for a particular type only accepts values of that particular type. The generic `lookupSerializer` function prods the compiler to actually distribute the union, if you were to inline it, the compiler would not distribute the union, so the function is actually necessary in spite of its trivial implementation.

Comment: Like the explanation thanks! FYI I've made the example with `Set` only to narrow down the transpiler issue and make the full example simpler... I do use a `Map` for finding the right serializer `const SERIALIZERS = new Map<SvgElementType, Serializer >()`